How to create multi-option BooleanField in wtforms under one label and a select all option with bootstrap-flask
I wanted to make a multi-option wtforms.BooleanField with one label in wtforms, flask_wtf
this is the piece of code that I wrote:
class InventoryRecorder(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    all_season = wtforms.BooleanField('all')
    spring_season = wtforms.BooleanField('spring')
    summer_season = wtforms.BooleanField('summer')
    fall_season = wtforms.BooleanField('fall')
    winter_season = wtforms.BooleanField('winter')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField("Save")

and this is template code:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% from 'bootstrap5/form.html' import render_form %}

{% block content %}
<main class="mb-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <!--TODO: render your registration form here-->
          {{ render_form(form) | safe }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
{% endblock %}

and what I get is a list of options which is ok.
I wanted to get it in a group and a select all option to select all options, is that possible??
